# Why when processing the second lightning the cancel button is not cancelling the operation?

Tags: c#, winforms

The logic:  When clicking the btnStartProcessing_Click it will start processing next click will stop processing. if clicking the button to stop the processing and it's in the middle of processing a lightning then it will wait for the current lightning processing to finish and then will end the overall process.

This is working fine when clicking the button in the middle of processing the first lightning or the third lightning fourth fifth sixth any lightning except the second one.

I can tell why when I click the cancel button and it's processing the second lightning and it's only the second one then when it's finishing processing the second lightning instead stop and cancel all the operation it keeps going on to the next lightnings.

The problem is only with the second lightning process.

The code is a bit long, but everything is connected.

Using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;
```

The top of form1:

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> lightningProcessingTaskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
private VideoCapture videoCapture;
private int totalFrames;
private int processedFrames;
private bool processingFrames;
private readonly int framesToCaptureAfterLightning = 4;
private string selectedLightningsFolderPath;
private string selectedVideoFilePath;
private bool paused = false;
private bool lightningDetected = false;
private List<string> lightningDirectories;
private int currentLightningIndex;
private List<string> lightningImages;
private int currentImageIndex;
private Logger logger;
```

The btnStartProcessing_Click event:

```
private async void btnStartProcessing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnVideoFileFolder.Enabled = false;
    btnSaveLightnings.Enabled = false;

    if (!processingFrames)
    {
        // Get the current date and time with the desired format
        string startTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        // Log the process start time
        logger.Log($"Process Started At: {startTime}", Color.Green);
        logger.Log("", Color.White); // Empty line

        processingFrames = true;
        btnStartProcessing.Text = "STOP PROCESSING";
        customProgressBar1.UpdateProgress(0);

        videoCapture = new VideoCapture(@"d:\lightnings1.mp4");
        totalFrames = (int)videoCapture.Get(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameCount);
        processedFrames = 0;

        // Create a new cancellationTokenSource for the current processing
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            await ProcessVideoFramesAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Handle cancellation
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always release resources and reset
            cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
            videoCapture?.Release();
            processingFrames = false;
            btnStartProcessing.Text = "START PROCESSING";

            // Enable the buttons and check conditions
            EnableButtonsAndCheckConditions();

            if (!lightningDetected)
            {
                logger.Log("Process Cancelled At: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"), Color.Red);
                logger.Log("", Color.White); // Empty line
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!lightningDetected)
        {
            paused = false; // Reset pause state if stopping
            if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                await Task.Delay(100); // Allow current lightning capture to complete before stopping
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await ProcessingLightning();
        }
    }
}
```

The ProcessingLightning method:

```
private async Task ProcessingLightning()
{
    // Simulate the lightning processing. Replace this with your actual logic.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // Simulate 3 steps of processing
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate a 1-second processing step

        if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
        {
            // Check if the main cancellation token is requested (indicating a full cancellation)
            if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Perform any cleanup or cancel logic here
                paused = false; // Reset pause state if stopping
                videoCapture?.Release();
                processingFrames = false;
                btnStartProcessing.Text = "START PROCESSING";

                // Signal that the lightning processing is canceled
                lightningProcessingTaskCompletion.TrySetResult(false);

                logger.Log("Process Cancelled At: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"), Color.Red);
                logger.Log("", Color.White); // Empty line

                return; // Exit the method
            }
            else if (!lightningDetected)
            {
                // Check if lightningDetected is false (assuming this is when you want to cancel the current lightning)
                // Perform any cleanup or cancel logic here for the current lightning
                paused = false; // Reset pause state if stopping
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
                cancellationTokenSource = null;
                await Task.Delay(100); // Allow current lightning capture to complete before stopping
                videoCapture?.Release();
                processingFrames = false;
                btnStartProcessing.Text = "START PROCESSING";

                // Signal that the lightning processing is canceled
                lightningProcessingTaskCompletion.TrySetResult(false);

                logger.Log("Process Cancelled At: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"), Color.Red);
                logger.Log("", Color.White); // Empty line

                return; // Exit the method
            }
            else
            {
                // Log the lightning processing canceled or ended with an empty line before and after
                /*logger.Log("", Color.White); // Empty line before
                logger.Log("Process " + (lightningDetected ? "Ended" : "Cancelled") + " At: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"), lightningDetected ? Color.Green : Color.Red);
                logger.Log("", Color.White); // Empty line after*/
            }
        }
    }

    // Signal that the lightning processing is complete
    lightningProcessingTaskCompletion.TrySetResult(true);
}
```

and the ProcessVideoFramesAsync method:

```
private async Task ProcessVideoFramesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    int framesCaptured = 0; // Track the number of frames captured after lightning
    string currentLightningFolderPath = null;
    int currentLightningStartFrame = 0;
    int folderNameCounter = 0;

    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using (Mat frame = new Mat())
            {
                videoCapture.Read(frame);

                if (frame.Empty())
                {
                    break;
                }

                lightningDetected = lightningDetected = LightningDetector.DetectLightning(frame); // Use the new class

                if (lightningDetected)
                {
                    if (currentLightningFolderPath == null)
                    {
                        currentLightningStartFrame = processedFrames + 1;
                        currentLightningFolderPath = Path.Combine(selectedLightningsFolderPath, $"Lightning{processedFrames + 1:D3}");
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(currentLightningFolderPath);
                    }

                    while (framesCaptured < framesToCaptureAfterLightning && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        using (Mat capturedFrame = new Mat())
                        {
                            videoCapture.Read(capturedFrame);

                            if (capturedFrame.Empty())
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                            string frameFileName = $"Frame{framesCaptured + 1:D2}.png"; // Example filename
                            await SaveLightningImageAsync(capturedFrame, currentLightningFolderPath, frameFileName);
                            DisplayFrameInPictureBox(capturedFrame);
                        }

                        framesCaptured++;
                        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken); // Optional delay between captured frames
                    }
                }
                else if (currentLightningFolderPath != null)
                {
                    int currentLightningEndFrame = currentLightningStartFrame + framesCaptured - 1;
                    string frameRange = $"[{currentLightningStartFrame:D4}-{currentLightningEndFrame:D4}]";
                    string lightningFolderName = $"Lightning{folderNameCounter.ToString("D3")}_{frameRange}";
                    Directory.Move(currentLightningFolderPath, Path.Combine(selectedLightningsFolderPath, lightningFolderName));
                    currentLightningFolderPath = null;
                    framesCaptured = 0; // Reset the counter
                    folderNameCounter++;

                    logger.Log("Lightning Detected: " + lightningFolderName, Color.Yellow); // Empty line
                }

                processedFrames++;
                float progressValue = (float)processedFrames / (totalFrames - 1) * 100;
                customProgressBar1.UpdateProgress((int)progressValue);

                await Task.Yield(); // Allow UI updates before continuing to the next frame
            }
        }

        // Finish capturing the current lightning before completing
        if (currentLightningFolderPath != null)
        {
            // Wait for lightning processing to complete before finishing
            await lightningProcessingTaskCompletion.Task;
        }

        customProgressBar1.UpdateProgress(100);

        // Enable the buttons and check conditions
        EnableButtonsAndCheckConditions();
    });
}
```

It's long code but since I don't know where the problem is and why it happens, yet I can't cut the code and add here only part of it because everything is connected.

Comment: So dodgy: `await Task.Delay(100); // Allow current lightning capture to complete before stopping`

Comment: So dodgy: `lightningProcessingTaskCompletion.TrySetResult(true);`

Comment: @Enigmativity i removed the line await Task.Delay(100); and changed to false the line lightningProcessingTaskCompletion.TrySetResult(true); so it will signal when cancelling.  but I tested it now and both the first and second lightnings it's  not cancelling.  the third lightning it will cancel after finishing processing but the first and second it's not working.

Comment: @Enigmativity i can upload the project to github.

Comment: `lightningProcessingTaskCompletion.TrySetResult(true)` returns a `bool` which you're ignoring. That's the dodgy thing there.

Comment: Good questions get answers within 15 of posting. Your question hasn't got answers after 18 hours. You need to improve the question. We really need a [mcve] to help us. That may mean you need to create a cut-down version of your app that demonstrates the issue that we can run for ourselves to see it happening. If I'm going to post an answer then, 9 times out of 10, I will write a fully working bit of code that shows you how to do it properly. It's only fair that you do the same when asking.